# How to generate java code from MoDisco java model within eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, eclipse-emf

I started looking into [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/). So far I can discover a java model from an existing java project and write transformations using [ATL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/) to modify my java model. However I was unable to generate java code for that modified java model. In [this demo](http://docatlanmod.emn.fr/MoDisco/MoDisco-Demo_September2011.htm) there is java code generated from a modified model. An [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/) launch configuration called `JPAProject_Regeneration` is used for that as can be seen in this screenshot:
[image: screenshot from MoDisco demo]

Does anyone know how that launch configuration looks like? Is there a tutorial that explains the creation of this launch configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned launch configuration can be [found in the eclipse svn](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/plugins/trunk/org.eclipse.modisco.usecase.java.samplerefactoring/LaunchConfigurations/5-JPAProject_Regeneration.launch?view=log&root=Modeling_MODISCO&pathrev=4848). However it isn't that helpful, because it heavily depends on a very specific local setup that includes hard coded absolute paths.

MoDisco also provides a discoverer in the plugin `org.eclipse.gmt.modisco.java.generation`. However this discoverer is registered under the wrong extension point and therefore unavailable from within the UI. See the [filed bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393037).

Also note that once the discoverer is registered correctly it is only applicable if the java model is within a file ending with `.javaxmi`.

*EDIT:*
The whole plugin `org.eclipse.gmt.modisco.java.generation` seems deprecated, because there is a new API for discovery. I built a new plugin that does the same as the mentioned MoDisco plugin based on the new API.